# Windows 8.1 PC not detecting my Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, sync

Windows 8.1 PC not detecting my Windows Phone 8.1. It's just acting as a charging point. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Look in Device Manager - does your phone show up under "Portable Devices" and/or "Universal Serial Bus devices"? Also, which phone do you have?

Comment: Also, try [this solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpnetwork/nokia-lumia-930-and-630-with-windows-phone-81-wont/f51ebc72-fe0f-42ec-ba75-e468c3fb763f) from a related issue.

Comment: Try unplugging it, remove it from device manager (on PC), reboot your phone, and plug it in again. Also, have you tried the Windows Phone App?

Comment: Neil, @Drowun - tried those, nothing changed

Comment: Device is showing under other devices. Model Lumia 620

Comment: Have you tried the solution at http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/7353/106 ?

Comment: Check this troubleshooting guide ; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2749484

Answer (score 1):

Check inside the usb port that the central "pins" have not bent to one side or the other. If they have bent you will get charge but no data which can cause this issue. Carefully push them back to the centre with a pair of tweezers and you will be up and  running again.