# Nokia Lumia 925 is not being recognised by my laptop

Tags: 8.1, lumia-925, pc

I'm having problems with my Nokia Lumia 925 not being recognised by my laptop. This has happened since I recently updated my phone to Windows Phone 8.1. My laptop runs Windows 8.1 Pro N 64-bit. In device manager I can see the Nokia Lumia 925 (RM-892) as a device but it has a yellow exclamation mark beside it.

I have tried the following with no success:

- Opening device manager and searching for drivers online - says no drivers exist for my device
- Downloading drivers and browsing for them in device manager - says not compatible
- Uninstalling device from device manager, and plugging in again - same happens; recognised but with yellow exclamation mark
- tried different USB ports but same effect
- tried different PC but not recognised at all

The phone worked fine before the update. Please help with any suggestions as to why it is not recognised.

Comment: Did u installed Zune in your Laptop? Get it here http://www.windowsphone.com/en-IN/How-to/wp7/zune-software

Comment: @Naveen Zune is not used with Windows Phone 8.x

Comment: Chris, when you removed the phone, did you also see if it showed up under "Universal Serial Bus devices" as well as "Portable Devices"

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've resolved this by going into Device Manager, right clicking, and selecting "Uninstall" on all the phone related options in the "Portable Devices" and "Universal Serial Bus devices" sections. Then unplug the phone, and after you've rebooted, and logged back on, you can plug the phone back in, and it should reinstall using the updated drivers for Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Stop IpOverUsbSvc.exe in Task Manager.
Plug in Your Phone
Start IpOverUsbSvc.exe in Task Manager.