# Nokia Lumia 930 and Windows 10 usb driver

Tags: windows-10, nokia-lumia-930

I have a Nokia Lumia 930 with Windows Phone 8.1, and when i try to connect it to my PC, Windows 10 Pro N, the usb drivers is not found. I have installed the Media Feature Pack, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231 for Windows 10. But it didn't help. So, is there someone who knows where to get the drivers? I have tried a lot of different searches, but almost all of then is about getting Windows 10 on the phone.

Kind regards
Steffen

---Edit - Update 2---
Sorry all, I have completely forgot about this question. Familly :( and work took all my time.
Well I have solved this problem by installing Windows 10, not the N version. And my phone is updated/upgraded to Windows 10 Mobile. And I can now see the phone in Explorer.
Before that it was with Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1, but that didn't work. Driver was missing, or something like that. But now it works, hmm.
Anyway, thanks for the answears. Both could be answears, tried them, so I will mark them as that. If I can, new to StackExchange/Stackoverflow.

---Edit - Update---
I have connected the phone to a Windows 7 pc, and it was found and worked as it should.
I have reinstalled Windows Device Recovery Tool, and restarted the pc. And connection my phone again, but this didn't work. The recovery tool can read the phone and software version. So there is some connection.

Comment: What is he device recognised as? The phone should just connect as an MTP device and not need specific drivers

Comment: Adding to the useful comment of @RowlandShaw I want to just mention the obvious here because sometimes stuff like that elude us: _Have you rebooted both the phone and the PC and tried again?_  This kind of behavior reminds me of simple bugs that get fixed by simply rebooting.

Comment: I have had restarted several times, tried running _sfc scannow_ hoping that is would help if there where some system files corrupted, and uninstalled Windows Phone Recovery Tool. Plus the extra it installed, WinUSB. Here is a picture of the device manager with my phone: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=59C8970D80D50988!411&authkey=!AG-VeFK7pjs_H44&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG The pc and phone has been restarted several times.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/7353/106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Lumia 920 and wasn't able to see my files but the phone was detected. Drivers were missing. This solution worked for me:

If you have windows 10 build 1511 install the following:

Media Feature Pack for Windows 10 N and Windows 10 KN editions (November 2015)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229

Now I am able to see my Lumia 920's folders, pictures, downloads, ...

Comment: Just so everyone knows, for _Windows 10_ version 1607 ("_Anniversary Update_") there's an [updated version (KB3133719)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3133719/media-feature-pack-for-n-editions-of-windows-10-version-1607) of the _Media Feature Pack_ (the previous version did not resolve the problem despite it claimed to have installed successfully).

Answer (score 1):

First, try connecting your phone to another PC. This way we will find out where's the problem. If the phone gets recognized on the other PC it means that *your* PC has the problem. If it doesn't it means that the phone has the problem.

If the phone has the problem then you should try a **soft reset** first, and if this doesn't work a **hard reset**.

A **soft reset** can be done by: `Settings > About > Reset your phone`.

A **hard reset** can be done using the [Windows Recovery Tool](http://download-fds.webapps.microsoft.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/WindowsPhoneRecoveryToolInstaller.exe) BUT since you can't connect to the PC this might be impossible. First, try using the Windows Recovery Tool cause it *might* recognize your device. If it doesn't, there's probably a hardware issue and you need to contact customer support.

If the issue is your PC then this post probably belongs to another site.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps may help you.

1. Go to C:\Windows\INF
2. Type "wpdmtp.inf" in search bar provided to the right of the
   address bar in Windows 10.
3. Once you found it, just right click on it and select install. It
   will take a very few seconds.
4. Connect your device to the pc.
5. Done.

Comment: This worked for me, as long as the device was connected to my PC.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the USB cable. The phone was charging OK, but in Windows no device was detected. Replaced the cable, and it worked.